# Is it possible to pass discriminated union tags as arguments?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

Is it possible to pass the type of a discriminated union tag to another function so it can use it for pattern matching?

Non working example of what I mean:

```
type Animal = Pig of string | Cow of string | Fish of string

let animals = [Pig "Mike"; Pig "Sarah"; Fish "Eve"; Cow "Laura"; Pig "John"]

let rec filterAnimals animalType animals =
    if animals = [] then
        []
    else
        let rest = filterAnimals animalType (List.tail animals)
        match List.head animals with
        |animalType animal -> animal::rest // <- this doesn't work
        |_ -> rest

printfn "%A" (filterAnimals Pig animals)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but supposing your example worked, you could combine all your pattern matching into one: `let rec filterAnimals animalType = function | [] -> [] | animalType animal :: rest -> animal::(filterAnimals animalType rest) | _ :: rest -> rest`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Discriminated unions works best if there is no semantic overlap between the cases.

In your example, each case contains the same component with the same meaning, a `string` indicating "the name of the animal". But that's a semantic overlap! The discriminating union will then force you to make distinctions you don't want to: You *don't* want to be forced to discriminate between the "name of a pig" and the "name of a cow"; you just want to think of "the name of an animal".

Let's make a type that fits better:

```
type Animal = Pig  | Cow  | Fish
type Pet = Animal * string

let animals = [(Pig, "Mike"); (Fish, "Eve"); (Pig, "Romeo")
```

With that type, filtering out non-`Pig`s is a one-liner:

```
animals |> List.filter (fst >> (=) Pig)
```

If not every animal has a name, use an option type:

```
type Pet = Animal * string option
```

You *would* use a discriminated union for your animals if you knew that, say, every `Pig` has a name, but no `Fish` does: those cases have no overlap.

Comment: Very useful comments! I'm just starting in F# and FP in general and my idea of a _type_ is somewhat tainted by all of my years in OOP.

Comment: @Søren Debois, what if pigs and cows have names, but fish don't? How would I model that?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin Awkward. You could introduce an intermediate `NamedAnimal` type; you could give up on discriminated unions and use classes and inheritance instead; or if you're lucky, the fact that exactly fish don't have names is irrelevant for your application and you can stick with the option type suggested above.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the `filterAnimals` function to take a [Partial Active Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) as input:

```
let rec filterAnimals (|IsAnimalType|_|) animals =
    if animals = [] then
        []
    else
        let rest = filterAnimals (|IsAnimalType|_|) (List.tail animals)
        match List.head animals with
        | IsAnimalType animal -> animal::rest
        | _ -> rest
```

Then you can define an Active Partial Pattern for pigs:

```
let (|IsPig|_|) candidate =
    match candidate with
    | Pig(_) -> Some candidate
    | _ -> None
```

And you can call the function like this (FSI example):

```
> filterAnimals (|IsPig|_|) animals;;
val it : Animal list = [Pig "Mike"; Pig "Sarah"; Pig "John"]
```

---

Actually, you can reduce the Partial Active Pattern like this:

```
let (|IsPig|_|) = function | Pig(x) -> Some(Pig(x)) | _ -> None
```

And it turns out that you can even inline them:

```
> filterAnimals (function | Pig(x) -> Some(Pig(x)) | _ -> None) animals;;
val it : Animal list = [Pig "Mike"; Pig "Sarah"; Pig "John"]
> filterAnimals (function | Fish(x) -> Some(Fish(x)) | _ -> None) animals;;
val it : Animal list = [Fish "Eve"]
> filterAnimals (function | Cow(x) -> Some(Cow(x)) | _ -> None) animals;;
val it : Animal list = [Cow "Laura"]
```

Comment: That works, however it bothers me that I would have to write patterns for all my different animals (who knows, it could be hundreds!). I'm still learning F# so it's probably me abusing the type system, but it frustrates me that I can't create helpers functions to process my unions.

Comment: If you have hundreds of different animals, I think it's safe to say that you shouldn't model them as a Discriminated Union with hundreds of cases...

Comment: In my cases they are actually tokens for a programming language (I'm writing a parser in F# as a learning project). To have to create "IsRightParen", "IsLeftParen", "IsKeyword" functions when F# already know the types doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: @monoceres BTW, if you're doing tokenizing and parsing, I highly suggest you check out FParsec. It's very powerful and elegant.

Comment: That's cheating! I'm actually trying to learn F#/Functional programming by implementing a parser :)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to pass just the tag, in order to be able to treat separately the tag and the string you can define them like this:

```
type AnimalType = Pig  | Cow  | Fish
type Animal = Animal of AnimalType * string

let animals = [Animal (Pig, "Mike"); Animal (Pig, "Sarah"); Animal (Fish, "Eve"); Animal (Cow, "Laura"); Animal (Pig, "John")]

let rec filterAnimals animalType animals =
    if animals = [] then
        []
    else
        let rest = filterAnimals animalType (List.tail animals)
        match List.head animals with
        | Animal (x, animal) when x = animalType -> animal::restwork
        |_ -> rest

printfn "%A" (filterAnimals Pig animals)
```

Alternatively you can use just a tuple of `AnimalType * string`

**UPDATE**

Regarding your question in the comments about what happens if the structure is not always the same, there's a trick you can use: you can compare the type of two Discriminated Unions since each tag is compiled to a different sub-class.

```
type Animal = 
    | Person of string * string 
    | Pig of string 
    | Cow of string 
    | Fish of string

let animals = [Pig "Mike"; Pig "Sarah"; Fish "Eve"; Cow "Laura"; Pig "John"]

let rec filterAnimals animalType animals =
    if animals = [] then
        []
    else
        let rest = filterAnimals animalType (List.tail animals)
        match List.head animals with
        | x when animalType.GetType() = x.GetType() -> x::rest
        |_ -> rest

printfn "%A" (filterAnimals (Pig "") animals)
```

But before going this way, you should think if you really need to model your problem like this.

Even if you decide to go with this structure I would rather use the built-in filter function, see the solution proposed by @polkduran.

Comment: What if I need my different animals to have different data types? For example, humans have both first and last names.

Comment: You will need to write more code, but for sure if want a function to accept just the TAG you need to define it separately.

Comment: OK, I see. Is any other type than discrinimated union more appropriate then?

Comment: What about type Animal = Human  of string * string | Animal of AnimalType * string

Comment: You can also define a DU to enclose string and string * string but I know you will loose the constraint that Person has to be string * string. There is a trick you can use knowing DU are compiled to classes, see the update.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness, I'll list this solution.
If you **[quoted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx)** your input, you'd be able to reason about the names of the tags:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type Animal = Pig of string | Cow of string | Fish of string

let isAnimal (animalType : Expr) (animal : Expr) =
    match animal with
        | NewUnionCase(at, _) ->
            match animalType with
                | Lambda (_, NewUnionCase (aatt, _)) -> aatt.Name = at.Name
                | _ -> false
        | _ -> false

let animal = <@ Pig "Mike" @>
isAnimal <@ Pig @> animal  // True
isAnimal <@ Cow @> animal  // False
```

This is admittedly quite verbose though, and it would become even more so if you wanted to quote a list instead of a single value.

A slightly different version, where we quote only the animal type, would let you easily filter lists of animals, as you need (at the price of some questionable comparison of strings):

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type Animal = Pig of string | Cow of string | Fish of string

let isAnimal (animalType : Expr) animal =
    match animalType with
        | Lambda (_, NewUnionCase (aatt, _)) -> animal.ToString().EndsWith(aatt.Name)
        | _ -> false

let animal = Pig "Mike"  // No quote now, so we can process Animal lists easily
isAnimal <@ Pig @> animal  // True
isAnimal <@ Cow @> animal  // False

let animals = [Pig "Mike"; Pig "Sarah"; Fish "Eve"; Cow "Laura"; Pig "John"]
let pigs = animals |> List.filter (isAnimal <@ Pig @>)
```

The latter version is not really superior to passing the tag name as a string.

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer your question directly but suggests an alternative way to achieve what you want.
You could filter your list using the existing high order function `List.filter` and pattern matching:

```
let pigs = animals |> List.filter (function |Pig(_)-> true |_->false )
```

I think this is a more idiomatic approach: you filter your list using a pattern, in this case you filter your animals keeping only those who satisfy the pattern `Pig(_)`.