# F# and negative match

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have a discriminated type:

```
type Item =
    | Normal of string * float32
    | Special1 of Item
    | Special2 of Item
```

And I have a function using this type:

```
let rec calcItem (i: Item ) =
    match i with
    | Normal(_, p) -> p
    | Special1(g) | Special2(g) -> (calcItem g) + 1
```

In my case, the **Special_*n*** types will be defined in the same form. So I am wondering if it is possible to use wildcard pattern to match all these types. The `_` match does not work, because it does not accept arguments.

Comment: You got duplicated Special1 in Your example code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009102/wildcard-for-type-when-matching-discriminated-unions/23009342#23009342) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796457/f-comparing-discriminated-unions-by-case-identifier).

As explained there you can use reflection or redesign your DU (this is what I would recommend).

Reflection:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type Item =
    | Normal of string * float32
    | Special1 of Item
    | Special2 of Item

let innerValue a =
    FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (a, a.GetType())
    |> snd
    |> Seq.head
    :?> Item

let rec calcItem (i: Item ) =
    match i with
    | Normal (_, p) -> p
    | specialN      -> calcItem (innerValue specialN) + 1.0f
```

Redesign the DU:

```
type Item =
    | Normal of string * float32
    | Special of int * Item

let rec calcItem (i: Item ) =
    match i with
    | Normal  (_, p) -> p
    | Special (_, g) -> calcItem g + 1.0f
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try with active pattern:

```
type Item =
    | Normal of string * float32
    | Special1 of Item
    | Special2 of Item

let (|Special|Norm|) (item) =
    match item with
    | Special1(g) | Special2(g) -> Special(g)
    | _ -> Norm

let rec calcItem (i: Item ) =
    match i with
    | Normal(_, p) -> p
    | Special(g) -> (calcItem g) + 1.0f
```

This does not completely remove the need of matching each SpecialN case, but it separates it from the calcItem function