# Extract value from union case

Tags: f#

In an Fsharp application, I have defined several union case types as

```
type A = A of String
type B = B of String
type C = C of String
```

I would like to define a function to extract the value from the union case instances.

```
let getValue( ctor: String-> 'a) = 
   ...implementation here
```

Is there anyway to achieve such task?
Thanks.

Comment: I can't see an obvious way to do this without reflection - although one might exist.

Comment: There was recently a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137032/f-and-negative-match/24137357#24137357) I think, otherwise can you expand your sample code? Type A of String is not valid F# code.

Comment: @Gustavo I have corrected the syntax error in the question. What I was trying to do is not using discriminated union.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```
type A = A of string
type B = B of string
type C = C of string

let a = A "hello"
let b = B "world"
let c = C "!"
```

There are many ways to extract those values, here are some:

**Individual unwrappers**

```
let getValueA (A v) = v
let getValueB (B v) = v
let getValueC (C v) = v

let valueOfA = getValueA a
let valueOfB = getValueB b
let valueOfC = getValueC c
```

**Method overload**

```
type T =
    static member getValue (A v) = v
    static member getValue (B v) = v
    static member getValue (C v) = v

let valueOfA = T.getValue a
let valueOfB = T.getValue b
let valueOfC = T.getValue c
```

**Function overload**

```
type GetValue = GetValue with
    static member ($) (GetValue, (A v)) = v
    static member ($) (GetValue, (B v)) = v
    static member ($) (GetValue, (C v)) = v

let inline getValue x : string = GetValue $ x

let valueOfA = getValue a
let valueOfB = getValue b
let valueOfC = getValue c
```

**Reflection**

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let getValue a =  
    FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (a, a.GetType())
        |> snd
        |> Seq.head
        :?> string

let valueOfA = getValue a
let valueOfB = getValue b
let valueOfC = getValue c
```

**Redesign your DU**

```
type A = A
type B = B
type C = C

type MyDU<'a> = MyDU of 'a * string

let a = MyDU (A, "hello")
let b = MyDU (B, "world")
let c = MyDU (C, "!"    )

let getValue (MyDU (_, v)) = v

let valueOfA = getValue a
let valueOfB = getValue b
```

**Redesign with interfaces**

```
type IWrapped<'a> =
    abstract getValue: 'a

type A = A of string with interface IWrapped<string> with member t.getValue = let (A x) = t in x        
type B = B of string with interface IWrapped<string> with member t.getValue = let (B x) = t in x
type C = C of string with interface IWrapped<string> with member t.getValue = let (C x) = t in x

let valueOfA = (a :> IWrapped<string>).getValue
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was looking for ONE function without many pattern matches to extract values from different types. Looks like the Reflection is about the only solution? I am a bit surprised that F# does not support this seemly simple scenario.

Comment: No it doesn't and it makes sense, a DU can be defined in many ways, not just a single-case, single string parameter. If all your DU will have always the same structure, why not change your design to reflect that? See the UPDATE.

Comment: I was following this exceptional blog http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/  Just thought there are better way to implement the "value" function than interface.

Comment: In that case you make them implement an interface. Keep reading the blog it explains how.

Comment: I did see how implementing interface can work, but that's a lot of repetitive code.

Comment: I just added an example, yes you have some repetitive code. But if you don't like it use one of the other alternatives, I would consider overloading as well, it has less repetitive code.