# Is there a less clumsy way to perform automatic numbering with infinite sequences?

Tags: f#

While the code I have does what I need, I feel I am missing some coding technique to implement this kind of stuff in a more concise way.

The goal is to compose items and give them an Id value along the way.
Here the code which I feel can be simplified and improved in many ways. If only I knew, how...

```
type Foo = | A of int | B of int | C of int
let ids startvalue = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + startvalue)
let makeA ids =
    A(Seq.head ids), Seq.skip 1 ids
let makeB ids =
    B(Seq.head ids), Seq.skip 1 ids
let makeC ids =
    C(Seq.head ids), Seq.skip 1 ids
let config = [makeA; makeA; makeC; makeB]
let create (ids : seq<int>) (cfg : (seq<int> -> Foo * seq<int>) list) : Foo list * seq<int> =
    let rec cre ids1 acc cl =
        match cl with
        | [] -> (acc,ids1)
        | x::xs -> 
            let v,ids2 = x ids1
            cre ids2 (acc @ [v]) xs
    cre ids [] cfg
let result : Foo list * seq<int> = create (ids 0) config
```

Which results in the very simple:

> val result : Foo list * seq = ([A 0; A 1; C 2; B 3], )

Somehow I feel there should be an easier way to accomplish the same.

In fact, I know one way to make it simpler but this would involve mutable state and memoization (and would thusly be probably considered worse):

```
let idgen startvalue =
    let v = ref startvalue
    fun () ->
        let result = !v
        v := !v + 1
        result
```

With the thusly received generator function I could get rid of all those tuples, at least and I could also get rid of `create` function and simply write:

```
let ids = idgen 0
let result =
    [
        A(ids())
        A(ids())
        C(ids())
        B(ids())
    ]
```

But there should also exist a "functional" way to get it done more simply.

Comment: If your code is working and you "just" want to make it better I'd post this on Code Review instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is Stackoverflow and not "FindTheBug". Honestly - the bug of this code is that it is not written as it should be written.

Comment: LOL it's not just "find the bug" but there is a more specific site on SE network...anyway...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes and if they add 50 more "more specific" sites noone will ask questions anywhere anymore and instead all will only discuss to which site the question belongs.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I think asking for a concise way to represent a general concept—here "adding consecutive ids"—is quite appropriate for SO.

Comment: @SørenDebois They complain if you provide code to clarify the question, they complain if you don't ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that what you want is to take two sequences, one of functions, the other of arguments, and produce new sequence by applying functions to corresponding arguments, where in your particular case arguments are successive integer numbers and functions are union case constructors. Would that be a correct assessment?

If so, here's what I would do:

```
let create args funs = 
   Seq.zip args funs 
   |> Seq.map (fun (arg, fn) -> fn arg)
   |> List.ofSeq

let result = create (ids 0) [A; A; C; B]
```

Comment: This would only work if the length of both sequences is the same. As the composition is application driven and the "id generator" is a utility, this would generally not apply.

Comment: Actually, no. This will work for sequences of any sizes, but it will stop when the shorter sequence "runs out", which is precisely what your initial code seems to achieve as well.

Comment: "Combines the two lists into a list of pairs. The two lists must have equal lengths." is written here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee353467(v=vs.100).aspx . I silently assumed it is the same with sequences... hm... but it is not! Bingo and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
type Foo = | A of int | B of int | C of int
let ids startvalue = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + startvalue)
let config = [A; A; C; B]
let create ids i cfg =
    let ids' = ids i
    let nextI = i + List.length cfg
    (Seq.map2 id cfg ids'), nextI
let result, nextI = create ids 0 config
let result2, nextI2 = create ids nextI config
```

There are several considerations here:

1. `A`, `B`, and `C` are constructors of the type `int -> Foo`. You may directly use them as functions and eliminate repetitive wrapper functions;
2. `Seq.map2` is able to process sequences of different length and ignore the remaining elements of the longer one;
3. `id` is a shortcut for `fun f number -> f number`, please use the longer one if you find `id` unclear
4. You may also refactor `ids` function into `Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.skip startvalue`.
5. At the end, you may convert a sequence into a `List` if you really need.

**Updated** to receive an keep `i` and `nextI`.

Comment: Good stuff. But as with the other answer, I now wonder if this approach makes me "lose" the state of the sequence. I.e. I could not go on composing more lists like that with ongoing numbering, right?

Comment: Updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: Given that `List.length` is _O(N)_, is it really a good idea to call it in `create`?

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, it certainly depends on the actual application. The alternative is dealing with sequence iterators or mutable state. The OP has asked for a concise and functional way.

Comment: @ildjarn I did indeed look for a functional solution, having showcased the "mutable" solution myself as part of the question. I take from all this, that I will not reject mutable solutions in situations like that on a basis of principle. Shorter code is usually the better code and I think the memoization version I outlined towards the end is indeed preferable here.

Answer (score 0):

As Fyodor pointed out in his answer, you really just want to apply your constructors to consecutive integers. You can use the built-in [mapi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353425.aspx) for that, writing your entire program as:

```
type Foo = | A of int | B of int | C of int
let config = [A; A; B; C]
let create offset = List.mapi (fun i f -> f (offset + i))
create 78 config
// val it : Foo list = [A 78; A 79; B 80; C 81]
```

Comment: As an aside, and I realise this may be just the example, you might want to lift the id outside of the discriminated union: `type Underlying = A | B | C;  type Foo = Underlying * int` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657000/is-it-possible-to-pass-discriminated-union-tags-as-arguments/22659530#22659530)).